# Is this a metorite captured on film or a bird/plane etc?

Tags: classical-mechanics

It is a shiny object in broad daylight, the distance seems quite far away, is there sufficient information in the footage  to ascertain if it is a meteorite captured on film or something else?

[image]

PS: Maybe somebody can grab a high def picture from somewhere?
I originally [posted this question on movie SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/meteorite-flash-above-congress-building-around-3502-mark-in-sleepy-hollow)

But I think it might be more suited for Phsysics SE.

Comment: Could be a butterfly a short distance from the camera.

Comment: There is not enough information in this two dimensional view to decide .  It could be a bird: once driving down  a road at sunset, I thought I saw a huge (kilometer wide) metalic(it shone) object on the west. As I neared it turned out to be a huge flock of starlings lifting up their wings (and showing the white color),  synchronously, so that it looked as a metal ship shining.

Comment: here is a fireball clearly http://www.amsmeteors.org/2016/06/daylight-fireball-over-midwestern-usa/